# Why I can't get geolocation?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I try to get the current location coordinates according to these [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation).

Here is how I do it:

```
var startPoint = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => { return position.coords });
```

but startPoint is undefined after the roe above is fired.

Any idea why startPoint is undefined?

Comment: Do you have access to navigator?

Comment: It's a callback...

Comment: @Vince, geolocation is enabled on the client

Comment: @ariel, any example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) is an asynchronous function, its result will only be set on the callback function:

```
var startPoint;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => { 
  startPoint = position.coords;
  // use startPoint here
});
// do not use startPoint here
```